# If $n \ge 1$, does it follow that $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n > n$

Tags: derivatives, induction, exponential-function

It seems to me the answer is yes.  Here's my reasoning:

For $n=1$, $\frac{3}{2} > 1$

and, $\frac{d}{dn}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}{n}\right) > 0  $

Using the quotient rule:

$\dfrac{d}{dn}\left(\frac{u}{v}\right) = \frac{u'v - uv'}{v^2} = \frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\left(\ln \frac{3}{2}\right)n - \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n }{n^2} > 0$ for $n \ge 1$

Am I correct?  Is there a more standard way to show this?

Comment: I suggest that you use induction to prove.

Comment: Are you my dad?

Comment: @LanierFreeman I've added also "induction" as tag if you agree.

Comment: I assume that you mean @LarryFreeman.  I agree.  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman Ops! Yes of course, your son! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can observe that

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n > n\iff 3^n >n2^n$$

and then proceed by induction.

Comment: Thanks!  A much simpler way to think about the problem.

Comment: @LarryFreeman Indeed, when $n$ is around, induction is always a nice way! It should be quite simple in that way. Let me know your try.

Comment: Yes.  Using induction.  Basis: $3^2 > 2*2^2$.  Assume for $n \ge 2, 3^n > n2^n$, then $3^n + 2*3^n > n2^n + n2^n + 2*2^n$  leading to $3^{n+1} > (n+1)2^{n+1}$

Comment: @LarryFreeman Yes it seems good, it’s an original way! I usually start from $$3^{n+1}=3\cdot 3^n>3n2^n>(n+1)2^{n+1}\iff 3n>2(n+1)\iff n>2$$ which requires to check the base case also for $n=3$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that is similar to that in your question, but perhaps a bit simpler.

---

Since
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\log(x)}x=\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}\tag1
$$
The function $\frac{\log(x)}x$ is increasing for $x\lt e$ and decreasing for $x\gt e$ and thus has a maximum of $\frac1e$.

The inequality in the question is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\log(n)}n\lt\log\left(\frac32\right)\tag2
$$
which is true since $\frac1e\lt\log\left(\frac32\right)$.

---

**Verification that $\boldsymbol{\frac1e\lt\log\left(\frac32\right)}$**

If we can assume that $\frac52\lt e\lt\frac{11}4$, then
$$
\frac1e\lt\frac25\tag3
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
e^2
&\lt\left(\frac{11}4\right)^2\\
&=\frac{121}{16}\\
&\lt\frac{243}{32}\\
&=\left(\frac32\right)^5\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$ shows that
$$
\frac1e\lt\frac25\lt\log\left(\frac32\right)\tag5
$$

Comment: That's really an original and nice derivation!

Answer (score 2):

Just check $f(x) = (\frac{3}{2})^x - x > 0$ for $x=1,2,3$.

Then for $x> 3$ you have $f'(x)= (\frac{3}{2})^x\ln \frac{3}{2} -1> 0$ anyway.

Comment: That's right.  Keep it simple.  Thanks.