# Factoring $\binom{3(n+1)}{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I have been trying to understand how to develop $\binom{3(n+1)}{n+1}$ [in this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771879/for-n-ge-4-does-it-follow-that-3n-choose-n-4n/2771942#2771942). I know that $\binom{3n}{n}+\binom{3n}{n+1}=\binom{3n+1}{n+1}$ but I need to get to this form $\binom{3n+3}{n+1}$ and I don't know how to proceed. The result is suppose to be $\binom{3n+3}{n+1}=\binom{3n}{n}(\frac{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+2)})$. I would like some help for this. Thanks!

Comment: It sort of follows from definition if you write out the factorials.

Comment: But why is there (n+1) at the denominator ((n+1)(2n+1)(2n+2)) isn't it supposed to be (n+1)! and isn't it supposed to have (3n)(3n-1)...(2n+3) at the numerator?

Comment: $\binom{3n}{n}=\frac{(3n)!}{n!(2n)!}$, now combine $n!$ with $(n+1)$ to get $(n+1)!$, and similarly combine $(2n)!$ with $(2n+1)(2n+2)$ to get $(2n+2)!$. The same for numerator, combine $(3n)!$ with $(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)$ to get $(3n+3)!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is how to derive the formula in the final line (rather than some other formula in the linked-to page), then note that

$$\begin{align}
{3n+3\choose n+1}
&={(3n+3)!\over(n+1)!(2n+2)!}\\
&={(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)(3n)!\over(n+1)n!(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}\\
&={(3n)!\over n!(2n)!}\cdot{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)\over(n+1)(2n+2)(2n+1)}\\
&={3n\choose n}{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)\over(n+1)(2n+2)(2n+1)}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $ \binom{n+1}{r}= \binom{n}{r-1}+ \binom{n}{r} $ several times gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{3n+3}{n+1} = \binom{3n}{n-2}+3 \binom{3n}{n-1}+3 \binom{3n}{n}+ \binom{3n}{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So to prove the linked result it suffices to observe that $\binom{3n}{n+1}> \binom{3n}{n}$ so we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{3n+3}{n+1} > 3 \binom{3n}{n}+ \binom{3n}{n+1} > 4 \binom{3n}{n} 
\end{eqnarray*}
and the result follows by induction.